# Save multiple hasMany data with saveAll() in CakePHP without writing id's in the view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, has-many

I FINALLY got my hasMany data to save using saveAll() - (an Event that hasMany Schedules).

I got it to work by repeating through the $this->data['Schedule'] data on the events/admin_edit.ctp, and building out all the fields for any/all schedules that are related to that event.

This seems fine (I think), but my question/problem is - I had to add the Schedule.id and Schedule.event_id fields as hidden fields so it'd know what data to save.  This seems awfully unsecure/wrong... 1) is it the right way to do it? and 2) Couldn't someone just edit the field to another ID, and hit save to update a different event's information?

My next assumption is that I'll have to build in some kind of checks into the controller before doing the saveAll()... but the more I write, the more complicated it's going to get, and the less Cake-like it seems.

Any thoughts/suggestions on how to better do what I'm doing, or insight as to what to check before doing the saveAll() is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't read carefully and I responded on how to do it on create. Looks like I handled it the exact same way in the past so I'm curious to see if there are alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have users that are allowed to edit their own events.  If that's the case, the easiest way is to add a validation rule that verifies that the user is allowed to edit the submitted schedule.

In your action, before the save() is called, inject the current user id into each record. ie:

```
$this->data['Schedule'][0]['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

This may not work exactly, but should get you close.  In your Schedule model, add a validation rule:

```
var $validate = array(
    'user_id' => array(
        'rule' => 'checkAuth'
        'message' => 'Nice try buddy.',
        'on' => 'update'
    )
);

function checkAuth() {
    $authorized = true;
    if(!$this->hasAny(array(
            'Schedule.id'=>$this->data['Schedule']['id'], 
            'Schedule.user_id' => $this->data['Schedule']['user_id']))) {
        $authorized = false;         
    }
    return $authorized;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome!  Gonna try as soon as I get a chance, and can't wait to verify it works and mark this as answer!  I didn't know you could validate w/ a function like that!  Thanks!  (if you happen to see this, and know if any pages that explain more about doing this, or a name for it?  THat would be awesome too.  Thanks, Tyler!

Comment: Yeah, the proper term is custom validation rules. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules

Comment: @Tyler - any thoughts on how I would check against the user being in the group "administrator" in the model?

Comment: Do you have a group_id FK in the users table? If so, you could inject the group_id also/instead, and write the validator against that.

Comment: @Tyler - I do have a group_id - not sure what you mean about the "inject the group_id" - maybe I should write this as another question.

Comment: In your controller, before sending the data to saveAll, iterate through each Schedule record, and do: `$this->data['Schedule'][$i]['group_id'] = $this->Auth->user('group_id');`.  You will then have access to it in your checkAuth function.

Comment: @Tyler - I actually meant... no matter which user creates the event (with it's schedule), an administrator should still be able to update it.  So - is there a way to check the current logged-in user's group in the schedule model?

Comment: I understand - inject both the user id and their group id, and check if they qualify...

Comment: @Tyler - how do I access the current user's group_id in the model?  (feel free to stop helping anytime - you've helped very much already, and I greatly appreciate it! :)

Comment: See post #6 in this thread ;)  You access group_id in the model by injecting it into the Schedule record while still in the controller action, before Schedule->save() is called. The user's group id should be available via AuthComponent's user() function. edit: And no problem at all - we were all new to Cake at some point!

Comment: oooooH... I think maybe I finally get it - if I set $this->data['Schedule'][0]['anything'] = 'something'; I can then reference that 'anything' value in the model... very cool - thank you!